# Getting json file on angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show the data collected from a json file but I do not get any output. What should I change in the code to make it work?. It's the first time I work with angular and it's costing me a lot of work. I can not find how to solve this. I appreciate your help very much.

JSON file (localhost/alertas.php):

```
[{
    "ID_ANUNCIO": "1",
    "TITULO": "Alerta1",
    "CUERPO": "Prueba de alerta1",
    "FECHA_INI": "2018-07-01",
    "FECHA_FIN": "2018-08-31",
    "TIPO_ANUNCIO": "1"
}, {
    "ID_ANUNCIO": "2",
    "TITULO": "Alerta2",
    "CUERPO": "No deberia mostrarse",
    "FECHA_INI": "2018-07-01",
    "FECHA_FIN": "2018-07-15",
    "TIPO_ANUNCIO": "1"
}, {
    "ID_ANUNCIO": "3",
    "TITULO": "Alerta3",
    "CUERPO": "Mostrando la alerta3",
    "FECHA_INI": "2018-07-09",
    "FECHA_FIN": "2018-10-11",
    "TIPO_ANUNCIO": "2"
}, {
    "ID_ANUNCIO": "4",
    "TITULO": "Alerta 4",
    "CUERPO": "No deberia mostrarse",
    "FECHA_INI": "2018-08-31",
    "FECHA_FIN": "2018-10-31",
    "TIPO_ANUNCIO": "2"
}]
```

Services:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ialerta } from './ialerta';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators"

@Injectable()
export class ServicioAlertas{
    constructor(private http: Http){

    }
    getAlertas() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost/alertas.php').pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
    }
}
```

Interface ialerta:

```
export interface ialerta{
    id_anuncio: string;
    titulo: string;
    cuerpo: string;
    fecha_ini: string;
    fecha_fin: string;
    tipo_anuncio: string;
}
```

Components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicioAlertas } from './alertas.services';
import { ialerta } from './ialerta';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alertas',
  templateUrl: './alertas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alertas.component.css'],
  providers: [ServicioAlertas]
})
export class AlertasComponent implements OnInit {

  alertas: ialerta[] = null;
    constructor(private empService: ServicioAlertas) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.empService.getAlertas().subscribe((empData) => this.alertas = empData);
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align:center;" *ngFor = "let alerta of alertas?.data">
  <p ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>{{ alerta.CUERPO }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want to get json from .php file? what is this url ? http://localhost/alertas.php

Comment: http://localhost/alertas.php show the json info.

Comment: your file should be .json . Eg alertas.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to use **`.data`** just

```
*ngFor = "let alerta of alertas"
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, but i have this error in console: ERROR Error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: The web page is displayed correctly with the data extracted from the json but in the firefox console it shows me the error that I have indicated

Comment: Is in the line 1 in the HTML file :(